# How to use maximum space of page to include long tables

Tags: longtable

I am writing a report and facing similar problem. I want to included a long table (spreading over many pages) in the appendix of the report. The tale contains around 100 columns but only four rows. I want to include maximum columns in a page. I am using the following latex command line. I would be grateful for a favorable consideration.

```
\begin{landscape} \setlength\LTleft{2pt} \setlength\LTright{2pt}
\begin{table}[htbp] \caption*{} 
\begin{longtable}{|l|p{4in}|l|p{4in}|}\hline HS2&Description&HS2&Description \\
 \hline 01&Live animals&20&Vegetable, fruit, nut, etc food preparations \\
 \hline 02&Meat and edible meat offal&21&Miscellaneous edible preparations \\
 \hline 03&Fish, crustaceans, molluscs, aquatic invertebrates nes&22&Beverages, spirits and vinegar \\
 \hline 04&Dairy products, eggs, honey, edible animal product nes&23&Residues, wastes of food industry, animal fodder \\
 \hline ... .... (up to 100 times)
\end{longtable} 
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.sx, you can format code sections using the `{}` button in the editor (your fragment was all in one line though). Please always post _complete_ small documents so people can test their answers, uncompilable fragments are less useful.

Comment: your example has 4 columns and (says it has) 100 rows. But your problem description says 100 columns and 4 rows?